# Bug with Spotlight Search. How to fix/restart?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight

There's a bug with my Spotlight Search. For example, when I search for "script editor", normally the search result would show the script editor app in Applications, but now it doesn't:

[image]

Without restarting the computer, is there a way to simply restart or refresh Spotlight Search?

(I've tried Relaunching Finder multiple times but it doesn't work.)

Finder itself is working fine, other than the fact that Ctrl-F Search will not show any results while being stuck at `Searching "foobar"`, and <Recents> (in the sidetab) shows a blank page and no results.

---

<sub>- I'm sure this bug can be fixed by restarting the computer, as it has happened several times before in the past.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked System Preferences > Spotlight, to see whether Applications are included in the results?

[image]

Otherwise, you may need to reindex your Spotlight database.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201716

Drag the disk "Macintosh HD" onto the Privacy panel of System Preference > Spotlight, and then click - to remove it from the window.

Comment: Yepp I haven't made any settings changes, Applications is checked. As for the reindexing operation, how safe is this operation? Would it be better simply to restart my computer? (Restarting the computer will fix the 'stuck' bug I know.)

Comment: It basically deletes the existing Spotlight database and creates a new one. Restarting your computer does not change the index. Also -- how old is the Mac? Does it have a mechanical hard drive? Have you verified the disk in Disk Utility?